An overlay timer that starts on LMB click/hold, stop & reset on release
Was able to start the time count by clicking LMB but could not find a way to stop and reset it.
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import time
from pynput import mouse

sg.theme('DefaultNoMoreNagging')

layout = [[sg.Text('0.0', size=(10, 1), justification='center', font=('Helvetica', 48), key='-TIMER-')]]

window = sg.Window('Timer', layout, finalize=True)

start_time = 0
timer_running = False

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    global start_time, timer_running
    if button == mouse.Button.left:
        if pressed:
            if not timer_running:
                start_time = time.time()
                timer_running = True
        else:
            if timer_running:
                elapsed_time = round(time.time() - start_time, 1)
                window['-TIMER-'].update('0.0')
                timer_running = False

listener = mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click)
listener.start()

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        listener.stop()
        break

window.close()

What I want is said in title, for example LMB click (and hold) somewhere on the screen. The timer should start as soon as I click, then reset to 0.0s and stop as LMB release.
By the above code, the count can start but cannot be stopped nor reset. Can't find a shortest or cleanest way to do the 'reset and stop' work. Don't know if I did the 'reset and stop' wrong or the monitoring part of releasing LMB wrong. Newbie to coding and thank you very much!

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

when I use print in on_click then I see it is executed when I press and when I release mouse. But rest of code seems useless - it doesn't start some loop or thread which will date time in window.

you have update() in wrong place, You should run .update('0.0')  in if pressed: if not timer_running: and .update(elapsed_time) in else: if timer_running: - and this will show 0.0  when you press mouse, and elapsed_time when you release mouse.

it seems you can use window.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", 'Press') and window.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", 'Release') to get values Press and Release in event, values = window.read()

Maybe this is close to what you're after...
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import time

layout = [  [sg.Text('Button hold example')],
            [sg.Text(key='-OUT-')],
            [sg.RealtimeButton('Click Me', key='-CLICK-')]  ]

window = sg.Window('Window Title', layout, finalize=True)
window.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', '-UNCLICK-')

started = False
start_time = 0
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    # print(event, values)
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        break
    if event == '-CLICK-' and not started:
        started = True
        start_time = int(round(time.time() * 100))
    elif event == '-UNCLICK-' and started:
        started = False

    if started:
        current_time = int(round(time.time() * 100)) - start_time
        window['-OUT-'].update('{:02d}:{:02d}.{:02d}'.format((current_time // 100) // 60,
                                                        (current_time // 100) % 60,
                                                        current_time % 100))

window.close()


A More Efficient Solution
Note that using the RealtimeButton element will potentially cause a LOT of CPU time to be consumed because you are getting events returned continuously as long as the button is held down.
The PySimpleGUI Timer API calls are helpful in creating/managing timer events.  They're more accurate than using the timeout parameter on window.read()
If you want more control/efficiency, then you can use the code below.  It starts a timer when you click the button that generates an event every 10 ms.  This is the line of code to change if you want to change the frequency of the events:
window.timer_start(10)

If the value was changed to 1000 (1 second):
window.timer_start(1000)

Then you'll see the timer in the window update once a second.
The full code:
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import time

layout = [  [sg.Text('Button hold example')],
            [sg.Text(key='-OUT-')],
            [sg.Button('Click Me')]  ]

window = sg.Window('Window Title', layout, finalize=True)
window.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', '-UNCLICK-')
window.bind('<Button-1>', '-CLICK-')

started = False
start_time = 0
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    # print(event, values)
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        break
    if event == '-CLICK-' and not started:
        started = True
        start_time = int(round(time.time() * 100))
        window.timer_start(10)      # Start a timer that will generate event every 10 ms
    elif event == '-UNCLICK-' and started:
        started = False
        window.timer_stop_all()

    if started:
        current_time = int(round(time.time() * 100)) - start_time
        window['-OUT-'].update('{:02d}:{:02d}.{:02d}'.format((current_time // 100) // 60,
                                                        (current_time // 100) % 60,
                                                        current_time % 100))

window.close()


it is good information about window.timer_start(), I didn't know it.

Added section on the Timer API calls to the new docs. Will check the cookbooks, etc.  There are demo programs already posted on them.

you could add this link in answer because it can be useful for other people - and in answer it will be more visible :)


A mouse listener is a threading.Thread

You cannot call method update to update the GUI under a sub-thread.
Call window.timer_start to periodly generate an event to update GUI, and call window.timer_stop to stop to update the GUI.
Example Code
import time
from pynput import mouse
import PySimpleGUI as sg

class Timer(mouse.Listener):

    def __init__(self, win, time):
        self.win = win
        self.time = time
        self.now = None
        self.timer_id = None
        super().__init__(on_click=self.on_click)
        self.start()

    def start_counter(self):
        self.now = time.time()
        self.timer_id = self.win.timer_start(self.time)

    def stop_counter(self):
        self.win.timer_stop(self.timer_id)

    def on_click(self, x, y, button, pressed):
        if button == mouse.Button.left:
            self.start_counter() if pressed else self.stop_counter()

layout = [[sg.Text("0.00s", justification="center", size=10, font=("Courier New", 40), key="Counter")]]
window = sg.Window("Counter", layout, finalize=True, keep_on_top=True)

timer = Timer(window, 10)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

    elif event == sg.TIMER_KEY:
        delta = time.time() - timer.now
        window["Counter"].update(f"{delta:.2f}s")

timer.stop()
window.close()


